# In Ruby (2.2) on Rails How Do I Have A Confirmation Box Pop Up Then Redirect To Another Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alert

In my controller I have an if condition and I want an alert/confirmation box to pop up if it is satisfied, then when the user clicks "ok" to redirect to another page.

I've tried

```
flash[:alert] = 'Successfully checked in'
redirect_to check_in_path
```

However it just skips the alert part and goes straight to the redirect without an alert message.

My Ruby version is ruby 2.2.6p396 and rails is 5.0.1

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tell us more, when what is satisfied you want the alert box to show? How are you getting to this controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a js.erb file. You can then use your existing rails code along with a js alert box. Js.erb files let you combine rails and JavaScript code in the same file. As mentioned flash[:alert] is not an alert box, alert is a css class.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is limited to the respond to HTTP request with HTML. And what you describe sounds more like a JavaScript `alert`. What you tried, if configured properly*, will simply show the flash alert when the check_in_path page is rendered.

* Get familiar with how the flash works, [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)

You have your controller set up correctly. The only other part I meant by configured correctly is that in your views you should display said flash message:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>
<% end -%>
```

It's common to use the name of the flash to style it to make to make it's intent clear; commonly red for failure, green for success.

Comment: Essentially a button is clicked (which links to a certain page) and I have a rule in the controller for this that if a certain amount of time has elapsed then this page cannot be accessed. If the time has elapsed I want something to tell the user why this page cannot be accessed (like the JavaScript alert) then redirect them to another page.

Comment: Like I said, that's outside of what Rails does. The controller simply gets a request and responds, it cannot do an alert and then respond. But you can redirect them the other page and tell them there, the reason they were redirected.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do as you suggest?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include further details on how to take it from what you have to what I descried. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follows

```
  render :update do |page|
    page << "alert('Successfully checked in')"
    page.redirect_to check_in_path
  end
```

but partial rendering in controller is most commonly used together with Ajax calls. so you may have to make an ajax call to your action from your view page. Hope this will help you